# Methods that return comments document body and comments parameters but they do nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, comments, parameters

Methods that return comments document the "body" and "comments" parameters, but they have no effect on the results, which cannot include comments and always include the body.

Specific methods:

- /answers/{id}/comments
- /comments/{id}
- /questions/{id}/comments
- /users/{id}/comments
- /users/{id}/comments/{toid}
- /users/{id}/mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body` and `comments` have been removed from those methods.

Comment: /users/{id}/mentioned still seems to have them.

Comment: @ColinD - woops, my bad.  This will be fixed in the next code push.